# building .apk from ionic project getting sdk certificate error

Tags: android, ionic-framework

while generating apk from ionic project getting some sdk error as in given image

[image: following given image]

Can anybody tell how we make setup of android sdk

Thnks

Comment: Did you at least read this?

Comment: @Selvin of course not. And you've been here long enough to know that it would be counterproductive : if you read stuff, you might as well RTFM and do the work, but SO is a place for other people to think and work for you, so why read stuff ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error you are getting; it is safe to say that the problem is from your Android SDK. You need to update your Android SDK Platform and/or install Android SDk Platform Version 25. The Android SDK Manager helps you download the SDK tools, platforms, and other components you need to develop your apps.

To open the SDK Manager from Android Studio, click Tools > Android > SDK Manager or click SDK Manager in the toolbar. If you're not using Android Studio, you can download tools using the sdkmanager command-line tool.

When an update is available for a package you already have, a dash appears in the check box next to the package.

1. To update an item or install a new one, click the check box so it shows a checkmark.
2. To uninstall a package, click to clear the check box.

Pending updates are indicated in the left column with a download icon . Pending removals are indicated with a red cross .

To update the selected packages, click Apply or OK, then agree to any license agreements.

[SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afA7o.jpg)